# function php with mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb

In the mongo database, the questions are stored in a document the name of the document is:  Questions, everyone have a text field

Make a php function add-question($text, $base) that adds a question in the database:

I started this, but i'm not sure, thanks to help me :

```
function add-question($text,$base){
    $base->insert($text)
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you "not sure" about? Did you try it and look what happened? Are the results what you expect? When not, how do the results differ from the desired results?

Comment: its an exercise for university, i have to make php functions with mongo database

Comment: That is irrelevant. Please answer my questions.

Comment: Do you have examples with php function with mongodb, because i know make php function but i dont know how with mongodb ?